# Pre-Processing Data in Caret and Making Predictions on an Unknown Data Set

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using the Caret package train function to fit a model and then predict to predict values on an unknown data set (which I then get feedback on so I know the quality of my predictions).  I'm having problems and I'm convinced it has to do with preprocessing the unknown data.

Briefly and simply, this is what I'm doing:

Pre-Process Training Data:

```
preproc = preProcess(train_num,method = c("center", "scale"))
train_standardized <- predict(preproc, train_num)
```

Train the Model:

```
gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = c(1, 5, 9),
                        n.trees = c(100,500),
                        shrinkage = 0.1,
                        n.minobsinnode = 20)



train.boost = train(x=train_standardized[,-length(train_standardized)],
                    y=train_standardized$response,
                    method = "gbm",
                    metric = "ROC",
                    maximize = FALSE,
                    tuneGrid= gbmGrid,
                    trControl = trainControl(method="cv",
                           number=5,
                           classProbs = TRUE, 
                           verboseIter = TRUE, 
                           summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                           savePredictions = TRUE))
```

Prepare unknown data for predictions:

```
...
unknown_standardized <- predict(preproc, unknown_num)
...
```

Make the actual prediction on the unknown data:

```
preds <- predict(train.boost,newdata=unknown_standardized,type="prob")
```

Note that the "preproc" object is the same one resulting from analysis of the training set and used to make the centered/standardized predictions on which the model was trained.

When I get my evaluation back my evaluation on the unknown data it is substantially worse than what was predicted using the training set (ROC using training data via cross validation is about .83, ROC using the unknown data that I get back from the evaluating party is about .70).

Do I have the process right?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You actually show the whole workflow using caret. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

In one sense, you are not doing anything wrong at all.

A predictor is likely to do better on a training sample as it has used that data to build the model.

The whole point of the training set is to see how well that model generalizes.  It is likely to "overfit" to the training data to a greater or lesser extent and to do somewhat worse on new data.

At least once you have your score against new data, you know the true accuracy of the model.  If that accuracy is sufficient for your purposes, then the model will be useable and (because you have done the training/test) robust to new data.

Now, it is possible that the model could be better if it was trained on a wider variety of data.  So to increase real accuracy, it might be worth using cross-validation to train it on multiple slices of the data - k fold cross-validation.    Caret has a nice facility for that.  http://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-estimate-model-accuracy-in-r-using-the-caret-package/